# Android ExpandableListView IndexOutOfBoundsException after remove item

Tags: android, expandablelistview, indexoutofboundsexception, removechild

Got IndexOutOfBoundsException after delete item from ExpandableListView.

My errors:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
>           at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)

My ListAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    BookmarkParentModel bookmarkParent = (BookmarkParentModel) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.header_bookmark, null);
    }

    TextView bookmarkHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_header);
    TextView bookmarkCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_count);
    bookmarkHeader.setText(bookmarkParent.getString1().trim());
    bookmarkCount.setText(bookmarkParent.getString2().trim());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    BookmarkChildModel bookmarkChild = (BookmarkChildModel) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_bookmark, null);
    }
    TextView letterName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.letter_name);
    TextView bookmarkDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_date);
    letterName.setText(bookmarkChild.getString1().trim());
    bookmarkDate.setText(bookmarkChild.getString2().trim());

    return convertView;
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: share full adapter class

Comment: Check size method?

Comment: Did you call `notifyDataSetChanged` after removing an item from your list?

Comment: this is my full listadapter code: https://pastebin.com/0pUfJvVN

Comment: @ReazMurshed yes, I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.header_bookmark, null);
    }

    if (groupPosition < getGroupCount()) {
        BookmarkParentModel bookmarkParent = (BookmarkParentModel) getGroup(groupPosition);
        TextView bookmarkHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_header);
        TextView bookmarkCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_count);
        bookmarkHeader.setText(bookmarkParent.getString1().trim());
        bookmarkCount.setText(bookmarkParent.getString2().trim());
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_bookmark, null);
    }

    if (childPosition < getChildrenCount(groupPosition)) {
        BookmarkChildModel bookmarkChild = (BookmarkChildModel) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        TextView letterName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.letter_name);
        TextView bookmarkDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_date);
        letterName.setText(bookmarkChild.getString1().trim());
        bookmarkDate.setText(bookmarkChild.getString2().trim());
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There must be an issue with your adapter and data size . Kindly share complete adapter class then i can resolve your problem precisely .

Or

check if you are updating the size after deletion of the data?

Comment: this is my full listadapter code: pastebin.com/0pUfJvVN

Comment: i cant access the link/

Comment: try with this link paste.ofcode.org/pizD84b8XcFVfaV5gYGh6R

Comment: you are not posting any link.